# positive look ahead and replace

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Recently I'm writing/testing regexps on https://regex101.com/.

My question is: Is it possible to do a positive look-ahead AND a replacement in the same "replacement"? Or just limited kind of replacement is possible.

Input is several lines with phone numbers. Let's say the correct phone number where the number of "numbers" are 11. No matter how the numbers are divided/group together with - / characters, no matter if starts with + 00 or it is omitted. 
Some example lines:

```
+48301234567
+48/30/1234567
+48-30-12-345-67
+483011223344556677
0048301234567
+(48)30/1234567
```

Positive look-ahead able to check if from the beginning until the end of line there are only 11 digits, regardless how many other, above specified character separating them. This works perfectly.

Where the positive look-ahead check is fine, I would like to delete every character but numbers. The replacement works fine until I'm not involving look-ahead.

Checking the regexp itself working perfectly ("gm" modes):

```
^(?:\+|00)?(?:[\-\/\(\)]?\d){11}$
```

Checking the replace part works perfectly (replace to nothing):

```
[^\d\n]
```

Put this into look-ahead, after the deletion of non new-line and non-digit characters from the matching lines:

```
(?=^(?:\+|00)?(?:[\-\/\(\)]?\d){11}$)[^\d\n]
```

Even I put the ^ $ into look-ahead, seems the replacement working only from beginning of the lines until the very first digit.

I know in real life the replacement and the check should/would go separate ways, however I'm curious if I could mix look-ahead/look-behind with string operations like replace, delete, take the string apart and put together as I like.

UPDATE: This is what would do the trick, however I feel this one "ugly" a bit. Is there any prettier solution?
https://regex101.com/r/yT5dA4/2

Or the version which I asked originally, where only digits remains: regex101.com/r/yT5dA4/3

Comment: Do you mean [this regex does not work for these data](https://regex101.com/r/zR6oO6/1)? You removed all non-digits, and now trying to match them? Aren't you looking for [`^(?:00)?\d{11}$`](https://regex101.com/r/zR6oO6/2)?

Comment: I'm trying to do the following two with the same regexp line:
- check if the current line (phone number in this case) format is match
- if match, do the following: delete everything but numbers

Comment: You can't achieve that with one regex that should match what it cannot match, or that matches just everything. Use 2 regexps: 1) remove all non-digits, 2) check if it conforms to some pattern (like the one I posted in the comment above).

Comment: Sorry I don't get what would you like to tell. If you copy paste the example data I included and you check every one of my regexp I've included you can see that the regexp working fine until I mix the look-ahead with something else. Once I've mixed, it expects me to specify the exact amount/place of the characters I want or don't want. Does not work anymore the "find any non-digit characters and delete them".
However you may be right about what I suspect: look-ahead/look-behinds can't really combine with other things in 1 line.

Comment: You should have posted the code you have, it would be easier to follow the logic.

Comment: Or, you could `if string matches ^(?:\+|00)?(?:[\-\+\/\(\)]?\d){11}$, then replace all in string using \D` . The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace/delete text with regex. Regex is just a tool for matching certain strings and then taking certain action depending on the matching text, eg. perform a substitution, retrieve the second capture group.

However it is possible to perform certain decisions within a regex engine, by using **conditionals**. The common syntax for this, with a lookahead assertion, is `(?(?=regex)then|else)`.

With conditionals you can change the behaviour depending on how the text matches the regex. For your example you could do something like:

`^(\+)?(?(1)\(|\d)`
If the phone number starts with a plus it must be followed by a bracket, else it should start with a digit. Although in your situation, this is not very useful.

If you want to read up more on conditionals in regex you can do so [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Comment: If I use regexp for the (linux/unix) "grep", it won't able to replace, just match or not match, however if I use in (linux/unix) sed, then I can replace while I can use regexp.

Check + replace in some easy case:
https://regex101.com/r/yJ3aY4/1

OR some perl 1 liner:

echo -e "There are many kind of fruit wine.\napple wine"|perl -pe 's/(?<=apple) wine/ cider/g'

What I would like to know if check + replace can use for more difficult cases, for example to remove all non-digits while I'm using look-ahead for pre-check. "If" working opposite way to me,not sure why: https://regex101.com/r/zR8sQ6/2

Comment: EDIT: This: https://regex101.com/r/zR8sQ6/2  does not work at all, it matches even the wrong line.